# Maintain counter field in postgres table

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, triggers, sequelize.js

I have twp tables one is `template` and another is `house`, `house` table has column **templateid** which is primary key of `template` table **id**.

Now ,template table has field **houseCount**, which maintain how current template has number of house.

so, every time when I made house entry with template, I will update **houseCount** in relavant template row of **template** table .

But when I update house with no template that time ,it dont perform decrement for that irrespective template row of **template** table

Comment: Write a database trigger to do this, if you really must have it. It is the only reasonable way to keep redundant data consistent.

Comment: Why not just create a view that shows that information?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I already created trigger But when I update house with templateid null then how can we update that old template id houseCount

Comment: Write the trigger correctly. If you want an answer, you'll have to show the trigger definition.